# Socket server, working on specific network interface address

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I have a simple tcp client server program. Client sends text, server prints it ito terminal. I need to make it so client can connect to server by ip address, no just a port. Tried changing something in my localhost server, but it only broke it and it doesn't work anymore. What's whong in it? 
Here's the server code:

```
int server(int port)
{
    int fd;
    struct ifreq ifr;
    char * addres;
    fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    /* I want to get an IPv4 IP address */
    ifr.ifr_addr.sa_family = AF_INET;

    /* I want IP address attached to "eth0" */
    strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, "em0", IFNAMSIZ-1);

    ioctl(fd, SIOCGIFADDR, &ifr);

    close(fd);
    addres=inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in *)&ifr.ifr_addr)->sin_addr);

    //until this part, i'm getting my em0 address to a variable which I want to use later
    //to specify on which address I want my server to be

    int s, s2, t, len;
    int z;
    struct sockaddr_in local, remote;
    char str[100];

    if ((s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
        perror("socket");
        exit(1);
    }
    local.sin_family = AF_INET;
    local.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(addres);          //inet_addr(inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in *)&ifr.ifr_addr)->sin_addr));
    printf("binder");
    if (bind(s, (struct sockaddr *)&local, sizeof(local)) == -1) {
        perror("bind");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (listen(s, 5) == -1) {
        perror("listen");
        exit(1);
    }

    for(;;) {
        int done, n;
        printf("Waiting for a connection...\n");
        t = sizeof(remote);
        if ((s2 = accept(s, (struct sockaddr *) &remote, (socklen_t *) &t)) == -1) {
            perror("accept");
            exit(1);
        }
        printf("Connected...\n");
        done = 0;
        do {
            n = recv(s2, str, 100, 0);
            if (n <= 0) {
                if (n < 0) perror("recv");
                done = 1;
            }


            if (!done) 
                printf("%s", str);
                fflush(stdout);
                sleep(1);
        } while (!done);

        close(s2);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It should start listening at given port, and on em0 interface address, but it seems to  be doing nothing at all. In driver function I just pass the int representing port which I want to use.

Can I connect my client with that server using ip address? 
My driver funtion chooses if I want to start a server or a client, it's all in one file.
To start a server i use:

```
./main.o -l [port]
```

and to start a client I'd want to use:

```
./main.o [address] [port]
```

Client seems to be working fine, just refuses to connect, only problem (as far as I'm aware) is a server. Maybe you'll catch what am I doing wrong, I'm sitting with it for couple of hours basically hopeless.

Comment: [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/) - It's is an excellent guide and tutorial for doing exactly what you are attempting to do. (Beej is a good old professor too)

Comment: What exactly is the use of converting the `ifr_addr` to a string and then converting it back to an address? Did you try to debug your code and check the values that you get (`ifr_addr`, `addres`, `inet_addr(addres)`)?